# How to change the path of precompiled header file of clang

Tags: c++, clangd

By default, it seems clangd creates pch files in system temporary path, i.e. /tmp/*.pch. What if I want to change it to a different location? I don't see clangd has any command line option for that. Any ideas?

`clangd -pch-storage=disk`

Answer (score 0):

The storage location can be changed by setting the TMPDIR environment variable to a different location. That seems to be the only way.